# Exporting data/images from Core Data on iOS so they can be imported on Android

Tags: android, ios, core-data, export

Is there an efficient way to export Core Data objects and images in such a way that it can be imported on an Android device (and vice versa) without having to POST to a server?

I came up with two options:

1. Export everything in JSON format, then parse it for importing. The issue with this is the Base64 encoded string of a `UIImage` is very large, and I'm not sure if quality is lost in this process.
2. Export as an archived package (.zip).  Have all images stored in a subdirectory of the package, then a path to the images is stored in JSON (rather than the Base64 string).

Option 2 seems to be the best, but there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I used [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) to compress a .json data file and all the user's images.  Then, I use a `UIDocumentMenuViewController` to give the user as many import/export options as possible.